# How to set Woocommerce Product Image above Details

Tags: css, woocommerce

http://elvinwebmarketingdemo.com/trebellart/artwork/bright-day-sunflower/

I was able to set the container for the image to 100% so that the product details would fall before, however for some strange reason the additional images (not the featured image) do not show where they normally do when doing this. I can't fathom why.

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, 

.woocommerce div.product div.images, 

.woocommerce-page #content div.product 

div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product 

div.images{
width:100%;
}
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image{
max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you define "normally"?

Comment: When you click on the other images, they should appear where the first one does, in a bigger size.